# d3.select method not working

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am new to datavis and the D3 library and I'm trying to follow the tut here http://mbostock.github.com/d3/tutorial/bar-1.html

When I run the code, nothing displays on my webpage, can anyone point out the problem??

I think its something to do with the d3.select method. When I run the code and inspect it, the body is empty, so Im assuming nothing is being created. Any help would be hugely appreciated!!!

```
<title>3Dtut - 1</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://mbostock.github.com/d3/d3.js?2.4.5">   </script>

<script type="text/javascript">
var data = [4, 8, 15, 16, 23, 42];  

//container for the bar chart
var chart = d3.select("body").append("div")
.attr("class", "chart");

//adding div elements to the bar chart
 chart.selectAll("div")
     .data(data)
     .enter().append("div")
     .style("width", function(d) { return d * 10 + "px"; })
     .text(function(d) { return d; });
</script>


<STYLE type="text/css">
.chart div {
   font: 10px sans-serif;
   background-color: steelblue;
   text-align: right;
   padding: 3px;
   margin: 1px;
   color: white;
 }
 </STYLE>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The problem is related to the position of your `<script> .. </script>` within the html document.

No `body` element exists yet at the moment that your script is being executed. That means that `d3.select("body")` will be empty, and no `div.chart` is being appended.

Try to move your `<script> .. </script>` inside the `<body> .. </body>` part. This will guarantee that the `body` element exists when your code is being executed.

Comment: you probably also want to mention that the `script` tag should be at the **end** of the body tag, to allow DOM to be fully loaded before the script is executed.

Answer (score 0):

Using the  inside the body makes it not only available to the  tag or any of the  but also executes it faster. Also as div is a tag u could create a class eg. one and then use it as d3.select(".one") so that it doesn't coincide.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not wish to put your `<script>` tags within the `<body>` element, you can also tell the browser to execute your d3 code (or any other JavaScript code) after the DOM is ready.

Using a library such as jQuery, you can use:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  // Your d3 code here
});
```

This will ensure that your scripts are executed after the whole DOM is ready, including the `<body>` element.

For reference, examples and a shorter version of jQuery ready function, see http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/.